# unpivot multiple metric columns into 2 different columns and introduce a label to track column name for both columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

source

```
id  value_a1    value_a2    value_a3    value_a4    value_b1    value_b2    value_b3    value_b4

1     1            1          1           1           1            1           1    
2     1            1          1           1           1            1           1    
3     1            1          1           1           1            1           1
```

target

```
id  value1  value1label value2  value2label
1    1      value_a1      1      value_b1
1    1      value_a2      1      value_b2
1    1      value_a3      1      value_b3
1    1      value_a4      1      value_b4
2    1      value_a1      1      value_b1
2    1      value_a2      1      value_b2
2    1      value_a3      1      value_b3
2    1      value_a4      1      value_b4
3    1      value_a1      1      value_b1
3    1      value_a2      1      value_b2
3    1      value_a3      1      value_b3
3    1      value_a4      1      value_b4
```

I wrote down a query:

```
SELECT ID value1,
       value1label,
       value2,
       value2label,
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          valuea1,
          valuea2,
          valuea3,
          valuea4,
          valueb1,
          valueb2,
          valueb3,
          valueb4
   FROM TABLE) P UNPIVOT (value1
                          FOR value1label IN (valuea1,valuea2,valuea3,valuea4))AS UNPVT UNPIVOT (value2
                                                                                                 FOR value2label IN (valueb1,valueb2,valueb3,valueb4))AS UNPVT1
```

but the issue is value1label and value2label are not in sync as in a1 to b1 and using order on any one disrupt the ordering.
if i order on value1label it goes from a1 then b1 and then b2,b3 and so on.

using union with unpivot value for each label results in null values as well which is not desired as it increase the number of rows

anyone can help me with this

p.s treat a1,a2,a3,a4 as alias for column heading for value_a1,value_a2,value_a3,value_a4
same is the case for b1,b2,b3,b4
 for simplicity i chose those values.

Comment: any one got a way around it ??

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what version of SQL Server you are using but you can unpivot the pairs of data `value_a1`/`value_b1` using `CROSS APPLY` instead of UNPIVOT.

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you can use the VALUES clause with CROSS APPLY, but you can also use UNION ALL:

```
select id, value1, value1label, value2, value2label
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select value_a1, 'value_a1', value_b1, 'value_b1' union all
  select value_a2, 'value_a2', value_b2, 'value_b2' union all
  select value_a3, 'value_a3', value_b3, 'value_b3' union all
  select value_a4, 'value_a4', value_b4, 'value_b4'
) c (value1, value1label, value2, value2label);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b41f/1). This gets your data into the same rows as you need:

```
| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE1LABEL | VALUE2 | VALUE2LABEL |
|----|--------|-------------|--------|-------------|
|  1 |      1 |    value_a1 |      1 |    value_b1 |
|  1 |      1 |    value_a2 |      1 |    value_b2 |
|  1 |      1 |    value_a3 |      1 |    value_b3 |
|  1 |      1 |    value_a4 |      1 |    value_b4 |
```

Comment: ah this is helpful, but i did something else , as for sql server version , it is 2008 R2...thanks so much for giving an alternative.